# SQL (clickhouse) grouping INSIDE window function

Tags: sql, window-functions, clickhouse

I need help with writing some equivalent of "group by" inside window function. I have a data in such format:

| user_id | day | task_id | task_score | task_pass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 1 | 0.95 | true |
| 1 | 01 | 2 | 0.7 | false |
| 1 | 03 | 2 | 0.95 | true |
| 1 | 04 | 2 | 0.9 | true |
| 1 | 05 | 5 | 0.85 | false |

Each day is guaranteed to have only one row per present task_id.
And I need a function that for each day-user would:

1. Grab data before that day including that day
2. Group data over task_id and calculate some aggregation function, for example, max(task_score)
3. Take these grouped values, calculate another aggregation function over them and write that in column. For example, average of max_score for each task.

End result should be like that:

| user_id | day | average_max_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 0.825 |
| 1 | 02 | 0.825 |
| 1 | 03 | 0.95 |
| 1 | 04 | 0.95 |
| 1 | 05 | 0.916 |

Basically, I want to group by one column inside window function.

Honestly, I don't even know how to approach this. Native and "simple" solution would be: take all tasks, cross join them with user-day table, then use window function like this one:

```
max(task_score) over (
  partition by user_id, task_id 
  order by day rows between 
    unbounded preceding
    and current row) as max_score_to_this_day
```

and then use group by over day, user_id:

```
select avg(max_score_to_this_day)
from table
group by user_id, day
```

---

This approach probably will work, but it will create some unreasonable amounts of data since not every user did every task, it will create user-day-task rows for days user have yet to touch task(and not every user will try every task), and in general this looks like a bad approach.

Is there any better way to do what I've described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. sorry about table name, I am really tired to write CREATE_TABLE/INSERT, I spend more time on CREATE_TABLE/INSERT than on the real query. I don't understand WHY people who ask questions make people WHO answer questions to do really stupid work.
2. you don't have day=2 in the input data. It's really confusing.

```sql
create table slava_ukraini(user_id Int64, day Int64, task_id Int64, task_score Float64, task_pass String )
Engine = Memory as 
select * from values (
(1,     01,     1,  0.95,   'true'),
(1,     02,     2,  0.7,    'false'),
(1,     03,     2,  0.95,   'true'),
(1,     04,     2,  0.9,    'true'),
(1,     05,     5,  0.85,   'false'));



select user_id, day, avg(max_task_score) avg_max_task_score from 
(
    select user_id, day, task_id, max(task_score) max_task_score from 
    (
      select user_id, day, arrayJoin(ga) g, g.2 task_id, g.3 task_score
      from (
          select user_id, day, 
                 groupArray( (day, task_id, task_score, task_pass) ) over (partition by user_id order by day rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  ga
          from slava_ukraini
      )
    ) group by user_id, day, task_id
) group by user_id, day
order by user_id, day

┌─user_id─┬─day─┬─avg_max_task_score─┐
│       1 │   1 │               0.95 │
│       1 │   2 │              0.825 │
│       1 │   3 │               0.95 │
│       1 │   4 │               0.95 │
│       1 │   5 │ 0.9166666666666666 │
└─────────┴─────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! "you don't have day=2 in the input data. It's really confusing." - well, this table is for task submits, so user can have zero task submitted or have several tasks submitted per one day. In my prev version I was fixing missing days by cross join with table that have every day-user possible in it, so I'll do something similar with that one.